# How to run PHP code inside PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have a class with about 10 methods that automate some tasks in a project I'm working on. I use PhpStorm and am looking for a way to execute various methods manually in the most convenient way possible. Ideally, there would be an interactive PHP console in PhpStorm that would allow me to create an instance of my class and then execute its methods but it's probably not there.

Is there a way to use PhpStorm's terminal or [Command Line Tools Support](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/running-command-line-tool-commands.html) to achieve what I'm looking for.

My current workaround is to create a PHPUnit test class and have 10 test methods for my 10 automation methods. PhpStorm can execute PHPUnit tests one by one so this kind of works but I need to maintain my test file so I'd rather not use this approach.

Comment: You can use the regular interactive PHP console (`php -a`) inside PhpStorm. But unit tests are the better long-term idea anyway, because you can repeatedly execute them consistently.

Comment: Tried that but the console wasn't responding to my commands. For example, I wrote `$myClass->myMethod()`, hit enter, the terminal window created a new line but nothing happened.

Comment: **Phing** anyone? PhpStorm supports it.